# wp7 How can i send with email a google or bing hyperlink with my current location

Tags: windows-phone-7, google-maps, hyperlink, location, bing-maps

I just want to send (email) my current location with hyperlink (when you click it, it will open google or bing map with the location) and not like text.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no support for HTML data in the email sent by the [EMailComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).
You can refer to [this discussion](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/83569/506134.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Easy: use the [EmailComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and in the text just set something with `maps:11.111,22.222`, where 11.111 is the latitude and 22.222 is the longitude.

Windows Phone email client will see the "maps:" text and auto-convert it to a link that opens with the Bing maps app!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
private void StartLocationButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // The watcher variable should be scoped to the class
    if (watcher == null)  
    {
        watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High); 
        watcher.MovementThreshold = 20; 
        watcher.StatusChanged += new 
                       EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(watcher_StatusChanged);  
    }
    watcher.Start();
}


void watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MyStatusChanged(e)); //Call BeginInvoke as discussed below…
}


void MyStatusChanged(GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Ready)
    {
        var link = String.Format("http://www.google.com/maps?q={0}+{1}", 
            e.Position.Location.Latitude.ToString("0.000000"), 
            e.Position.Location.Longitude.ToString("0.000000"));

        EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();
        emailComposeTask.To = "send@mail.com";

        emailComposeTask.Body = link;

        emailComposeTask.Subject = "GPS";
        emailComposeTask.Show();

        //Stop the Location Service to conserve battery power.
        watcher.Stop();
    }
}
```